# Creating a WCF PUT Rest service

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, .net-4.0, put

I have a simple REST web service in WCF that is declared as follows:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT",UriTemplate = "comptatge/add",RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public void GravaComptatge(MyDataContract contract)
{
    ...
}
```

where `MyDataContract` is a class with simple properties.

Now I send a put Request using fiddler to see if it works OK. In the body I send JSON with the same properties as `MyDataContract` but it's not working. I get a 400 Bad Request HTTP error. What am I doing wrong here? The service is hosted in a MVC app using ServiceRoute. Other GET services work OK.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happened to me before, and adding `Content-Type: application/json` in the request headers was the solution.

Comment: When using xml as your data format the content-type string is conveniently 'application/xml'.